# ASP.NET 5 beta8 Custom File Provider with Autofac

Tags: autofac, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a default ASP.NET Web Application in which we want to use a custom file provider.

```
public class CustomFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When we configure the provider using the following code it works fine and the custom file provider gets called by the framework.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        // replace the fileprovider with the custom file provider
        options.FileProvider = new CustomFileProvider();
    });
}
```

When we extend the configuration with a custom di container like Autofac the custom file provider isn't called anymore. This used to work fine in beta5.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        // replace the fileprovider with the custom file provider
        options.FileProvider = new CustomFileProvider();
    });

    // Create the Autofac container builder.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Populate the services.
    builder.Populate(services);

    // Build the container.
    var container = builder.Build();

    // Resolve and return the service provider.
    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

Did something change on how to use a custom file provider?

Answer (score 0):

[There is an existing issue with the Autofac integration that is being worked through that addresses this exact thing.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/659)